# Linux, вопрос по символу |

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Для чего в некоторых консольных командах используется знак `|` (вертикальная черта)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это так называемый конвейер, позволяющий передать вывод одной команды непосредственно на вход другой. Например, `ls | wc -l` передаст вывод команды `ls` команде `wc -l`, и таким образом осуществится подсчет количества записей в текущем каталоге - `ls` выдаст текст (на самом деле, набор байт), состоящий из нескольких строк, а `wc -l` их посчитает. А `cat file.txt | grep -i michael` передаст содержимое file.txt на вход команды grep, которая найдет все строки с вхождением `michael`.

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](http://xgu.ru/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Comment: Добавлю, что по-английски обычно называется pipe.

Answer (score 6):

"труба" используется для передачи стандартного вывода одной программы в стандартный ввод другой.
Например можно написать

```
grep bla-bla file.txt
```

Тогда грип будет искать текст bla-bla в файле file.txt . Но Грип загружает весь файл в память и ему может этой самой памяти не хватить и он вывалится в ошибку.
Тогда мы можем передать этот файл построчно:

```
cat file.txt | grep bla-bla
```

В этом случае программа cat считывает построчно файл и передаст каждую отдельную строчку grep`у и он не утыкается в полку памяти.

Comment: С чего вы собственно взяли, что в первом случае grep загрузит весь файл в память?

Comment: На практике. Обрабатывал большой файл при прямом скармливании грип падал, поглащая память. Была Centos6. А Вы считаете, что он тоже построчно считывает файл?

Comment: При построчном разборе файла существует возможность наличия одной очень длинной строки, которая вызовет ООМ.

Comment: И grep и cat тоже работают не построчно, а через кольцевой буфер. Читают и пишут блоками. И могут вывести часть строки, потом продолжение, сразу несколько строк и кусок последней и т.д. grep ещё и динамически меняет размер буфера, но это не связанно откуда он читает данные, а зависит от самих данных и опций.